# Align views in a Compose row

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I'd like to align items in a row like this:

```
(START)TEXT1    ||      TEXT2(END)
```

|| = > middle of the row

- If TEXT1 is long enough (it reaches over the center) it should be broken to multiple lines.
- TEXT1 should be aligned to the left, TEXT2 should be aligned to the right.

[image: Example row, the amount should be aligned to the left]

So far I have used following code:

```
@Composable
fun RowBalance(modifier: Modifier = Modifier, title: String, value: String){

    Row(modifier = modifier.padding(top = 8.dp, bottom = 8.dp)) {
        Text(text = title, modifier.weight(1f))
        Spacer(Modifier.weight(1f))
        Text(text = value, modifier.weight(weight = 1f, fill = false))
    }
    Divider(thickness = 0.5.dp, color = Color.LightGray)
}
```

Comment: So what is the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the only missing piece in your code is `textAlign` for your texts; here is a code I tested to produce your requested results:

```kotlin
@Composable
fun RowBalance(modifier: Modifier = Modifier, title: String, value: String){

  Row(modifier = modifier.padding(top = 8.dp, bottom = 8.dp), verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically) {
    Text(text = title, modifier = Modifier.weight(weight = 1f), textAlign = TextAlign.Start)
    Spacer(Modifier.weight(1f))
    Text(text = value, modifier = Modifier.weight(weight = 1f), textAlign = TextAlign.End)
  }
  Divider(thickness = 0.5.dp, color = Color.LightGray)
}
```

I also used the `verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically` to center the children of the row vertically; that way, if your `Text1` is with multiple lines, the other text will be in the vertical center (if this is not your requested behavior, you can delete it)!

[image]